# How to suppress the error message when dividing 0 by 0 using np.divide (alongside other floats)?

Tags: python, numpy

My attempt:

```
import numpy as np
np.seterr(divide='ignore')
a=np.array([4/3,0,0])
b=np.array([1,0,0])
np.divide(a,b)
```

The ouput I get:

```
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
array(1.33333333,        nan, nan])
```

If I ask it again:

```
np.divide(a,b)
```

then no RuntimeWarning is displayed.

I'm happy with the array that is output, but I don't want the error message; that is what I thought seterr would fix.  How can I get rid of the warning?  (I would rather not write a for loop that makes exceptions for 0/0.)

Comment: Why not `try..except`?

Comment: Doesn't 'except' stop the code from running? I am happy with 'nan' as an answer, I just don't want the error to display.

Comment: Errors stop the code from running. [`except`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) doesn't stop the code from running unless you tell it to.

Comment: exception handling is the best practice , other option is asked if the second number is zero , cannot divide :)

Comment: Is there a way to just suppress the message, because the way it handles the error is by putting in 'nan', which is basically what i would do anyway?

Comment: There is no way to suppress the warning, just it tells you that something is wrong with your code

Comment: It's the `0/0` as opposed to `1/0` that's giving problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
np.seterr(invalid='ignore')
```

or

```
np.seterr(all='ignore')
```

From the `seterr` docs:

> ```
> - Invalid operation: result is not an expressible number, typically
>   indicates that a NaN was produced.
> ```

`1/0` produces a `FloatingPointError: divide by zero encountered in true_divide` error/warning.

`0/0` produces a `Warning: invalid value encountered in true_divide` error/warning.

`all` will catch both.

`errstate` can be used to temporarily change `np.seterr`.

```
In [1472]: with np.errstate(invalid='print'):
    y=np.divide([1.2,0,0],[1,0,0])
   ......:     
Warning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
```

`warnings` are normally issued the first time the problem arise in a run, and then are silent.