# Numpy where and division by zero

Tags: python, numpy

I need to compute `x` in the following way (legacy code):

```
x = numpy.where(b == 0, a, 1/b)
```

I suppose it worked in [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) (as it was in a [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7) code), but it does not work in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) (`if b = 0` it returns an error).

How do I make it work in python-3.x?

EDIT: error message (Python 3.6.3):

```
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: Why is it working in python 2? You are dividing 1/0 which is illegal. Did you use b=0 in python 2?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I guess (I might be wrong) that in Python 2x the 3rd expression was not evaluated if the first one is true.

Comment: I just tested it in both 2.7 and 3.6. Same: `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide`

Comment: @jp_data_analysis "ZeroDivisionError: division by zero"

Comment: if b is 0, your condition is met, so a is returned. If that fails there is something wrong with your a. Otherwise dividing by zero doesn't make any sense in any context

Comment: @Henry Please always include the error message in your original post. Also, it seems like this errors out both in Python 2 and 3, which makes your question unclear.

Comment: `1/False`==`ZeroDivisionError: division by zero`

Comment: @henry - we need to know what `a` and `b` are here. With them both as arrays, this doesn't cause a `ZeroDivisionError` for me in either version, but both give the `RuntimeWarning` (if any element of b is zero). With `b` as an `int`, I get the `ZeroDivisionError`.

Comment: Why hasn't anyone mentioned python's `all()` method? it will short-circuit in a chain of conditions when it finds ANY falsey condition.

Comment: The python `all` does short-circuit, but the `np.all` does not.  If `b` is an array with possible 0 elements, I don't think `all` will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) documentation states:

> If `x` and `y` are given and input arrays are 1-D, `where` is
>       equivalent to::
>
> ```
>     [xv if c else yv for (c,xv,yv) in zip(condition,x,y)]
> ```

So why do you see the error? Take this trivial example:

```
c = 0
result = (1 if c==0 else 1/c)
# 1
```

So far so good. `if c==0` is checked first and the result is `1`. The code does not attempt to evaluate `1/c`. This is because the Python interpreter processes a *lazy* ternary operator and so only evaluates the appropriate expression.

Now let's translate this into `numpy.where` approach:

```
c = 0
result = (xv if c else yv for (c, xv, yv) in zip([c==0], [1], [1/c]))
# ZeroDivisionError
```

The error occurs in evaluating `zip([c==0], [1], [1/c])` before even the logic is applied. The generator expression itself can't be evaluated. As a function, `numpy.where` does not, and indeed cannot, replicate the lazy computation of Python's ternary expression.

Comment: thanks have been searching for the answer to the warning I was getting!

Comment: so generally you are suggesting to not to care so much about such a thing? got a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64747346/numpy-divide-by-zero-encountered-in-true-divide-on-np-where/64747383

Answer (score 16):

`numpy.where` is not conditional execution; it is conditional *selection*. Python function parameters are always completely evaluated before a function call, so there is no way for a function to conditionally or partially evaluate its parameters.

Your code:

```
x = numpy.where(b == 0, a, 1/b)
```

tells Python to invert *every* element of `b` and then select elements from `a` or `1/b` based on elements of `b == 0`. Python never even reaches the point of selecting elements, because computing `1/b` fails.

You can avoid this problem by only inverting the nonzero parts of `b`. Assuming `a` and `b` have the same shape, it could look like this:

```
x = numpy.empty_like(b)
mask = (b == 0)
x[mask] = a[mask]
x[~mask] = 1/b[~mask]
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly then, the `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide` I get actually comes from the condition selection, and it's just telling me that some conditions were impossible?

Comment: @roganjosh it comes from the division itself which is not lazy. But nans/infs are discarded by the selection.

Comment: @AndrasDeak which makes sense, but I'm wondering why it tells me anything at all in this case since the whole point is to try avoid such cases. I'm not sure where such a warning might be useful.

Comment: `where` already gets a divided array. Division happens before the call. There's nothing `where` can do to stop that. Try just computing the division.

Comment: In my opinion, the question is why doesn't `np.where(b == 0, a, 1/b)` [fails for `b=0`] evaluate in the same way as `(a if b==0 else 1/b)` [works for`b=0`]. I think it's a valid question and non-obvious to someone not aware of how `np.where` is implemented.

Answer (score 8):

A old trick for handling 0 elements in an array division is to add a conditional value:

```
In [63]: 1/(b+(b==0))
Out[63]: array([1.        , 1.        , 0.5       , 0.33333333])
```

(I used this years ago in `apl`).

---

`x = numpy.where(b == 0, a, 1/b)` is evaluated in the same way as any other Python function.  Each function argument is evaluated, and the value passed to the `where` function.  There's no 'short-circuiting' or other method of bypassing bad values of `1/b`.

So if `1/b` returns a error you need to either change `b` so it doesn't do that, calculate it in context that traps traps the `ZeroDivisionError`, or skips the `1/b`.

```
In [53]: 1/0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-9e1622b385b6> in <module>()
----> 1 1/0

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
In [54]: 1.0/0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-99b9b9983fe8> in <module>()
----> 1 1.0/0

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
In [55]: 1/np.array(0)
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[55]: inf
```

What are `a` and `b`?  Scalars, arrays of some size?

---

`where` makes most sense if `b` (and maybe `a`) is an array:

```
In [59]: b = np.array([0,1,2,3])
```

The bare division gives me a warning, and an `inf` element:

```
In [60]: 1/b
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[60]: array([       inf, 1.        , 0.5       , 0.33333333])
```

I could use `where` to replace that `inf` with something else, for example a `nan`:

```
In [61]: np.where(b==0, np.nan, 1/b)
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[61]: array([       nan, 1.        , 0.5       , 0.33333333])
```

The warning can be silenced as @donkopotamus shows.

An alternative to `seterr` is `errstate` in a `with` context:

```
In [64]: with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    ...:     x = np.where(b==0, np.nan, 1/b)
    ...:     
In [65]: x
Out[65]: array([       nan, 1.        , 0.5       , 0.33333333])
```

[How to suppress the error message when dividing 0 by 0 using np.divide (alongside other floats)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688667/how-to-suppress-the-error-message-when-dividing-0-by-0-using-np-divide-alongsid)

Comment: the question is some naive person (me) might expect it to evaluate like: `(1 if c==0 else 1/c)`. This code works perfectly fine for `c==0`. There seems to be an implementation detail which makes it different. I've tried to highlight this in my answer.

Comment: Frankly, @jp_data_analysis, I believe your answer missed the point.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis, it's not an implementation detail, it's basic Python syntax.  Python `if` (and `and` and `or`) does 'short-circuiting', but that's done by the Python interpreter.  `numpy` doesn't mess with that.

Comment: But  `a if b==0 else 1/b`  is a special syntactic expression, not a function.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to disable warnings in `numpy` while you divide by zero, then do something like:

```
>>> existing = numpy.seterr(divide="ignore")
>>> # now divide by zero in numpy raises no sort of exception
>>> 1 / numpy.zeros( (2, 2) )
array([[ inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf]])
>>> numpy.seterr(*existing)
```

Of course this only governs division by zero in an array. It will not prevent an error when doing a simple `1 / 0`.

In your particular case, if we wish to ensure that we work whether `b` is a scalar or a `numpy` type, do as follows:

```
# ignore division by zero in numpy
existing = numpy.seterr(divide="ignore")

# upcast `1.0` to be a numpy type so that numpy division will always occur
x = numpy.where(b == 0, a, numpy.float64(1.0) / b) 

# restore old error settings for numpy
numpy.seterr(*existing)
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using this:

```
x = (1/(np.where(b == 0, np.nan, b))).fillna(a)
```