# Does numpy.where(condition, f(x), f(y)) evaluate the f(y) is condition is true?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

When using `numpy.where(condition, f(x), f(y))`, I originally thought numpy `where` does not evaluate `f(y)` if the condition is `True`. However it seems to be not true

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[0, 1, 2, float('nan'), 4, 5]})
df['y'] = np.where(df['x'].isnull(), -1, np.maximum(1, df['x']))
df
```

I got the following warning:

> "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in maximum"

and sometime it just gives me an error and stop executing the code.

How to fix that issue?

Comment: Is there are reason you don't want to use panda's `apply`?

Comment: The answer is you can't fix this via `numpy.where`. Dup explains why. But there are many other ways to implement your logic: `pd.DataFrame.loc` [vectorised with conditions], `pd.DataFrame.apply` [thinly veiled loop] come to mind.

Comment: It seems to me that pd.apply is much slower comparing to np.where.

Comment: Can you explain little bit more of using pd.DataFrame.loc? Thanks.

Comment: @C.Tanaka See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49760286/7207392). `np.maximum` also has a keyword argument `where` that can be used exactly the same way as I describe for `np.log`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, thanks very much.