# Python error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I know why this error occurs. The reason is well documented. And I know how to avoid this error with some inefficient code (see the last bit of the question). But I don't know how to write an efficient implementation and avoid this error.

Here is the code:

```
pdf_exp=lambda x,lam=1:lam*exp(-lam*x) if x>=0 else 0

def graph(funct, x_range):
    x=np.array(x_range)
    y=funct(x)
    plt.plot(x,y,'r--')
    plt.show()

graph(lambda x: pdf_exp(x), np.linspace(-10,10,10000))
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
----> 3     y=funct(x)
----> 1 graph(lambda x: pdf_exp(x), np.linspace(0,10,10000))
----> 1 pdf_exp=lambda x,lam=1:lam*exp(-lam*x) if x>=0 else 0
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
Use a.any() or a.all()
```

When I make the change

```
pdf_exp=lambda x,lam=1:lam*exp(-lam*x)
```

then this runs without error but the plot is incorrect. But I really need to include that bit of code in there.

If I make the change suggested by the error message, I get another error message or an incorrect plot. This change:

```
pdf_exp=lambda x,lam=1:lam*exp(-lam*x) if (x>=0).all() else 0
```

produces this error:

```
x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10000,) and (1,)
```

And either of these changes

```
pdf_exp=lambda x,lam=1:lam*exp(-lam*x) if (x>=0).any() else 0
pdf_exp=lambda x,lam=1:lam*exp(-lam*x) if x.any()>=0 else 0
```

produce this incorrect plot:

[image: Incorrect plot]

This plot is incorrect because the y-values should be zero for x<0. This is the purpose of the code "if x>=0 else 0".

Of course I can change the implementation of the graph function to get this to work:

```
def graph(funct, x_range):
    y_range=[]
    for x in x_range:
        y_range.append(funct(x))
    plt.plot(x_range,y_range,'r--')
    plt.show()
```

But it would be nice to get the original version to work since it would seem to be more efficient.

Comment: Uhm... It doesn't tell you to remove the if-else, it tells you to add `any()` or `all()`. What happens if you add `(x >= 0).all()`?

Comment: In your code, `x` is a numpy array.  In the edited-in plot, x is a float.  Not the same thing.

Comment: I don't get it... Did you attempt to change the scaling depending on whether there are negative values, or did you try to "vectorize if"?

Comment: I'm not changing scale. The function and plot should be zero for negative values of x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just multiply your expression by `(x>=0)`

```
pdf_exp = lambda x,lam=1: lam*exp(-lam*x)*(x>=0)
```

This works because a boolean array is just interpreted as 1s and 0s in the context of arithmetic operations. E.g.

```
x = np.array([-1,2,3,-3])
print(x>=0)               # [False  True  True False]
print(x*(x>=0))           # [0 2 3 0]
```

Comment: Wow, that's really cool. I see that it works but I don't immediately see why it works. I will investigate. If you want to add a comment about why this works, I'd really appreciate that as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This error is produced when a boolean array is used in a scalar context such as an `if` statement:

```
lambda x,lam=1:lam*exp(-lam*x) if x>=0 else 0
```

This only works if `x` is scalar or a single element array.  If `x` is an array with several elements then `x>=0` is a boolean with the same number of elements.  **verify this for yourself**

```
a if c else b
```

is a scalar Python expression.  It returns either `a` or `b`.  It does not act elementwise on `a`,`b` and `c`.

```
np.where(c, a, b)
```

does return a mix of `a` and `b` depending the value of `c`.

```
np.where(x>=0, lambda x,lam=1:lam*exp(-lam*x), 0)
```

But beware that all elements of the `a` expression are evaluate by Python before passing to `where`.  So don't use it if you need to skip the evaluation for certain values of `x` (there was a recent question about this involving `np.log(x)`, [python numpy where returning unexpected warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49760092/python-numpy-where-returning-unexpected-warning)).

There are other ways of doing this conditional assignment.  But the first thing is to understand why you got this `ValueError`.

Comment: Thank you. I have reworded my question to make clear that I understand why this error occurs. The question is how to write an efficient implementation while avoiding the error.