# numpy.where - Calculating True statement, even if the condition is False

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have two variables that got zeros `s1 = 0` and `s2 = 0`, and a dataframe (there are more columns, but not relevant for this case):

```
    xyz 
0    2      
1    2      
2    2      
3    0     
4    0
```

I tried to create a new column using `np.where`:

```
df['c'] = np.where((df['xyz']>0) & (s1 > 0) & (s2 > 0), 1/s1, 0)
```

However it is raising ZeroDivisionError. Why it is calculating `True` case, even if the condition is `False`. How should I get the desired result?

Comment: Now I understood that python functions evaluate all inputs before executing. But in this case, how would I get the wanted result?

Comment: `1/s1` is always computed on every element of `s1`. `np.where` then check the condition and looks up the corresponding values. You could use `1/np.divide(1,s1, where=s1>0)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang, when using a `where` in a `ufunc` like `divide`, you should also provide an `out` parameter. Otherwise the not-where values will be unpredicatable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48696344/numpy-where-and-division-by-zero

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks, good to know, although, the non-where is not that important in this case.

Comment: Is there a better solution with pandas?