# Numpy divide by zero encountered in true_divide on np.where()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

When I got `np.where` that tries to avoid division by zero, I am still getting the error, even when `p_arr - 0.5` should be always `> 0`.

```
mo = np.where(p_arr > 0.5, -6.93/(p_arr - 0.5), 10)
```

> RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide

> mo = np.where(p_arr > 0.5, -6.93/(p_arr - 0.5), 10)

Any idea why and how to fix that? Additionally is there any way to debug it properly, so the error would show what was the exact value from p_arr?

Some tests:

```
x = np.where(p_arr > 0.5, p_arr, 1)
print(np.all((p_arr - 0.5 != 0))) # FALSE
print(np.all((x - 0.5 != 0))) # TRUE
```

Comment: Well, *presumably* it is happening wherever `(p_arr - 0.5) == 0`

Comment: Note, this is a *warning*, not an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pseudocode for `np.where`:

```
def np_where(chooser, true_opt, false_opt):
    out = np.empty(chooser.shape, dtype = true_opt.dtype) 
    out[~chooser] = false_opt
    return out
```

Importantly, `true_opt` is generated *before* calling the function.  So if anything in it raises an error, the interpreter never gets to call `np.where` - even if `np.where` would never use the parts of `true_opt` that raise the error.

You can get rid of the `divide by zero` errors, but don't use `np.seterr` as recommended in the other answer - that will shut it off for the whole session and may cause problems with other bits of code.  You can do it like this:

```
with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    mo = np.where(p_arr > 0.5, -6.93/(p_arr - 0.5), 10)
```

To find out where your error was coming from, just use:

```
np.where(p_arr == 0.5)
```

Which should give you the coordinates where you were getting the `divide by zero` error

Comment: so basically I shouldn't care much about it or how to make it right (and fast)?

Comment: Oh yeah, that wasn't an answer, it was just showing what your problem is.  My bad, one sec.

Comment: Showing what's wrong is, in my opinion, a perfectly good answer.  We (at least I am) are here to teach, not just provide quick fixes.

Comment: ok thanx, the function is more complicated than in example, and I am sometimes getting overflow error as well, any way to debug it without manually traversing through the array? to show x,y of the array or the value?

Comment: Not that I can tell from that limited amount of information, no.  Better to ask another question than change your requirements in a comment.  If this was helpful, please remember to mark solved.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this:

`np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')`

Comment: forgot to mention it's a python 3, it doesn't matter, and it shouldn't matter in python 2, as the second argument is 0.5, so if any of them are float, the result will be float

Comment: maybe on (-6.93/(p_arr - 0.5)). at some point in your array you have 0.5 - 0.5 so you cant divide by zero "-6.93/0"

Comment: that's why I am using `np.where` with `p_arr > 0.5`

Comment: and? don't get what are you talking about; I removed the exp(), as without it it's the same

Comment: I think that np.where is doing the division first before evaluating the condition, and then choosing which one to store. Try doing this:
import numpy as np
p_arr = 0.5
mo = np.where(0.4 > 0.5, -6.93/(p_arr - 0.5), 0)
print(mo)
This should return 0, but you get an error. 
Probably if you put np.where inside an if else could work

Comment: but how can I put it into `if` when it's an array, `np.where()` is an `if` for arrays

Comment: Try adding this:
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')