# Numpy more verbose information about warnings while using np.where

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I am using numpy (`np.where`) to calculate some indicators (pretty complicated formulas) on spatial data arrays. Sometimes when I operate on them, I am getting warnings like:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  mo_arr = np.where(self.p > 0.5, mo+42.5*(self.p - 0.5)*np.exp(-100.0/(251.0-mo))*(1.0 - np.exp(-6.93/(self.p - 0.5))), mo)
```

Is there any easy way to get the x,y of the field that caused the warning or do I have to refactor lots of code chunks to traverse the arrays manually to be able to extract such an info?

Second question: Can I force `np.where()` to work on `float128`? There is no `dtype=` option.

Third question: Can I force it to set given value when it overflows inplus and minus that value if it overflows inminus?

Comment: For a start evaluate the 3 arguments first on separate lines.  `where` just allocates elements based on the true/false values the first.

Comment: What are the ranges of `mo` and `self.p`?

Comment: hard to tell... i mean it's some value from some complicated mathematical formula based on some thousands of 1000x1000px spatial images, self.p is like max 100, min 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only expression you have involving `exp()` is

```py
mo+42.5*(self.p - 0.5)*np.exp(-100.0/(251.0-mo))*(1.0 - np.exp(-6.93/(self.p - 0.5)))
```

It is when computing this that you get the overflow. This happens prior to the evaluation of `np.where()`. The overflow happens when the result of `np.exp()` is greater than the largest float. Assuming double precision (the default), this is `1.7976931348623157e+308` (can be found by `np.nextafter(np.inf, 0)`), the natural log of which is about `709.8`. So `np.exp(709)` is fine, while `np.exp(710)` overflows and returns `np.inf` as the result (try it out!).

To find the culprit(s), just check which arguments to `np.exp()` are greater than `709`. As you have two `np.exp()`, do something like

```py
a = -100.0/(251.0-mo)
b = -6.93/(self.p - 0.5)
a_bad_indices = np.where(a > 709)[0]
b_bad_indices = np.where(b > 709)[0]
print('Bad a:', a[a_bad_indices], 'with indices', a_bad_indices)
print('Bad b:', b[b_bad_indices], 'with indices', b_bad_indices)
```

#### Question 2

Note that `np.where()` works fine on `float128`. To do the calculation using `float128`, your `self.p` and `mo` needs to be `float128`. The `np.exp()` will then take this into account.

#### Question 3

You can just let the overflow happen and then set all (positive or negative) infinite elements to some other value. Use `np.isinf` to do the check. Or you can manipulate the data prior the overflow by doing a `> 709` check on the non-exponentiated data.

Comment: ok that's case specific, but I guess that the answer to my question is that there is no way to generally output in the warning the "coordinates" of mo_arr in such a case, am I right?

Comment: @FlashThunder Not without rewriting the internal NumPy code that emits the warning.

Comment: sad, that should have been implemented

Answer (score 1):

As with your [Last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64747346/numpy-divide-by-zero-encountered-in-true-divide-on-np-where), you can get rid of the warning by using `np.errstate`:

```
with np.errstate(divide = 'ignore', over = 'ignore'):
    mo_arr = np.where(self.p > 0.5, mo+42.5*(self.p - 0.5)*np.exp(-100.0/(251.0-mo))*(1.0 - np.exp(-6.93/(self.p - 0.5))), mo)
```

Now just look for the places where the array is not finite (overflows will have `np.inf` output):

```
bad_coords = np.where(~np.isfinite(mo_arr))
```

Comment: isn't 1.0 - inf == -inf ?

Comment: . . . yes?  What is the problem?

Comment: don't know, well still not .isfinite() i guess, I'm trying to find out the cases when it's not infinity, but some big number ... is it possible that it generates for example float128, not infinity and then it does overflow float64? or the it ends up as inf as well?

Comment: `np.exp` will overflow any type of `float` if the argument is relatively large, even `float128`.  You probably want to look for locations where `mo - 251.0` or `0.5 - self.p` are very small and positive, because that's where you'll overflow - `np.exp(-np.inf)` doesn't overflow, it just becomes `0.0`